# Quartz scheduler is not working

Tags: java, cron, quartz-scheduler, scheduler

I have created one scheduler :

```
SchedulerFactory sf = new StdSchedulerFactory();
Scheduler sched = sf.getScheduler();
Trigger trigger1 = (Trigger) 
newTrigger().withSchedule(DailyTimeIntervalScheduleBuilder.dailyTimeIntervalSchedule().startingDailyAt(new TimeOfDay(8,0)).endingDailyAt(new TimeOfDay(11,0)).withInterval(1, IntervalUnit.DAY));

Date ft = sched.scheduleJob(job, trigger1);
```

But it is throwing an Exception :

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: org.quartz.TriggerBuilder cannot be cast to org.quartz.Trigger
```

How can i fix this error?

Answer (score 4):

You forgot to call `.build();` method on the [TriggerBuilder](http://quartz-scheduler.org/api/2.0.0/org/quartz/TriggerBuilder.html). The code should look like this:

```
newTrigger().withSchedule(
 DailyTimeIntervalScheduleBuilder.dailyTimeIntervalSchedule()
    .startingDailyAt(new TimeOfDay(8,0))
       .endingDailyAt(new TimeOfDay(11,0))
          .withInterval(1, IntervalUnit.DAY))
             .build();
```

Comment: I tried ur code..Now i getting error like this..Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid repeat IntervalUnit (must be SECOND, MINUTE or HOUR).
 at org.quartz.DailyTimeIntervalScheduleBuilder.withInterval(DailyTimeIntervalScheduleBuilder.java:179)

Comment: Yeah, the error message is obvious: it seems that `DailyTimeIntervalScheduleBuilder` only accepts seconds, minutes or hours, not days. maybe you need another type of scheduler, ,check the quartz api

Comment: actually purpose is scheduler should run every night starting 00:00 to 5:00 ..without repeatation..then how can i modify above code??

Comment: It's not clear what you mean. From 00:00 to 05:00, but it should be a repetition between these hours. Every half hour? Every 10 minutes? Or maybe the scheduler start at 0 hours every night?

Comment: the task scheduled on every day night in between midnight(00.00) to (5:00 AM).Ideally i will call one function inside this scheduler.When it is reached 5:00 AM ,i have to stop the scheduled task.

Comment: There is no need to stop the scheduler. You can start it at midnight, the scheduler will call your function, finish and will stop itself until the next day at midnight. But you should post another question for this as we are getting very long with the comments and your need is different from the original question.

Comment: i already posted that question.still dodnt get a proper answer..http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14208056/quartz-scheduler-time-between